# Dictionary to Dataframe with keys as index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Having this dictionary

```
{'ON':                   time     atm   rr25    bf25   rr10   bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.0895 -0.008  0.0015 -0.014  0.004,
 '1W':                   time     atm  rr25   bf25   rr10    bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.0785 -0.01  0.002 -0.017  0.0065,
 '2W':                   time     atm   rr25    bf25   rr10     bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.0795 -0.011  0.0025 -0.019  0.00837,
 '1M':                   time    atm    rr25    bf25    rr10     bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.077 -0.0115  0.0025 -0.0207  0.00925,
 '2M':                   time    atm    rr25    bf25    rr10     bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.075 -0.0115  0.0025 -0.0207  0.00937,
 '3M':                   time      atm   rr25     bf25    rr10     bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.07325 -0.012  0.00255 -0.0222  0.00969,
 '6M':                   time      atm    rr25     bf25     rr10    bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.07175 -0.0125  0.00265 -0.02375  0.0102,
 '9M':                   time      atm    rr25     bf25     rr10    bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.07125 -0.0125  0.00295 -0.02375  0.0115,
 '1Y':                   time    atm    rr25   bf25     rr10    bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.071 -0.0125  0.003 -0.02381  0.0117,
 '2Y':                   time    atm    rr25    bf25     rr10     bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.072 -0.0125  0.0032 -0.02375  0.01248}
```

I would like to convert it to this dataFrame

[image]

I tried different approaches by using pd.DataFrame.from_dict but didn't help

Comment: can you post the snippet code of the input of the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat(data).droplevel(1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                   time     atm   rr25    bf25   rr10    bf10
ON  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.0895 -0.008  0.0015 -0.014  0.0040
1W  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.0785 -0.010  0.0020 -0.017  0.0065
```

Data

```
>>> data
{'ON':                   time     atm   rr25    bf25   rr10   bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.0895 -0.008  0.0015 -0.014  0.004,
 '1W':                   time     atm  rr25   bf25   rr10    bf10
 0  2022-03-29 23:00:00  0.0785 -0.01  0.002 -0.017  0.0065}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify the format of your input? It does not look like a dictionary to me.

Also, try:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).T
```

Comment: I suppose it's a dictionary of dataframes.